# Jquery Ajax JSONP request not working on Chrome, works fine on FireFox

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I am using Jquery (and Jquery mobile) to make a mobile website..testing on desktop Chrome/Firefox.

When on chrome the JSONP ajax never reaches the server (can see the server access logs). The same works fine on Firefox.

Looking at firebug for chromes shows nothing on the console..no error/success nothing.

Looking at chrome developer tool shows:

> Refused to load the script 'http://example.com/radagast/backend/alatarHandler/test/getLocation.php?callback=jQuery1102014860787917859852_1430659361646&_=1430659361647' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

The code is:

```
var serverUrl = "http://example.com/radagast/backend/alatarHandler/test/getLocation.php";

    $.ajax({
    url: serverUrl,
    async: false,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    callback: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'yourcallback',
    success: function (result) {
            alert('Ajax sucess ' + result);
            $("#message").html("location sent");
        }

    });
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you looking to make it work, figure out why it's not working, understand why it's not working, ...?

Answer (score 0):

My Bad...

I was using some html template..which had the following meta tag that was blocking XSS.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```